# Object doesn't rotate in Unity 5.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

For some unknown reason my object doesn't rotate on trigger enter, it does print object's tag, so collision detection is alright.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    print(collider.gameObject.tag + " entered");
    transform.Rotate(0,45,0);
}
```

Script is attached to the door i want to rotate which has RigidBody and box collider attached. Any ideas?

Also noticed 3 errors when rotating it manually, see pic:  [image]

Comment: can you see the log output when you run it?

Comment: yes i can, so no idea why it doesn't rotate. I have also noticed in log window 3 error when i rotate it in scene: chunkY >= 0 && chunkY <= 0xffff             ;    terrainInstanceHashes.find (instances[i].instanceID) != terrainInstanceHashes.end ()
;     chunkX >= 0 && chunkX <= 0xffff

Comment: make sure rigidbody component has `Is Kinematic` unckecked and `freez rotation constraint` for y axis is also unchecked

Comment: A good alternative is to use `Rigidbody.AddTorque` when using rigidbody.

Comment: Another option you can use is animator to create door opening animation and play it when it hits trigger. As for the error is unity bug for lightmaps http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/baking-errors-chunky-0-chunky-0xffff-and-terraininstancehashes-find.317879/. One question does your car has animator component? if it has then check weather your door component is attached in the animation clip. The rotations/Position/Scale are not modified if used in the clips played by animator. For that they need to be updated in LateUpdate().

Comment: Looks like its marked Static (see top right corner), try disabling static batching and try then?

Comment: that was it, lost almost an hour trying to figure it out, thanks!